# The address total model should be extended from Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract

Tags: magento-1.9

I've just launched a site and it returns this error when trying to add a product to the shopping basket.

The address total model should be extended from Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract.

http://www.securatot.co.uk/izi-go-modular-black-cab

Any help would be great.  Magento 1.9

Comment: You are using a model which doesn't extend `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract`

Is there any other problem?